# How to get the occurrence of words while using isin on a split sentence (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on text analysis and try to quantify the value of sentence as the sum of the value assigned to some words if they are in the sentence. I have a DF with words and values such as:

```
import pandas as pd
df_w = pd.DataFrame( { 'word': [ 'high', 'sell', 'hello'],
                          'value': [ 32, 45, 12] } )
```

Then I have sentences in another DF such as:

```
df_s = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': [ 'hello life if good',
                                   'i sell this at a high price',
                                   'i sell or you sell'] } )
```

Now, I want to add a column in `df_s` with the sum of the value of each word in the sentence if the word is in the `df_w`. To do so, I tried:

```
df_s['value'] = df_s['sentence'].apply(lambda x: sum(df_w['value'][df_w['word'].isin(x.split(' '))]))
```

The results is:

```
                      sentence  value
0           hello life if good     12
1  i sell this at a high price     77
2           i sell or you sell     45
```

My problem with this answer is that for the last sentence `i sell or you sell`, I have twice `sell` and I was expecting 90 (2*45) but `sell` has been considered only once so I got 45.

To solve this, I decided to create a dictionary and then do a `apply`:

```
dict_w = pd.Series(df_w['value'].values,index=df_w['word']).to_dict()
df_s['value'] = df_s['sentence'].apply(lambda x: sum([dict_w[word] for word in x.split(' ') if word in dict_w.keys()]))
```

This time, the result is what I expected (90 for the last sentence). But my problem comes with larger DF, and the time to perform the method with `dict_w` is about 20 times longer than the method with `isin` for my test case.

Do you know an way to multiply the value of a word by its occurrence within the method  with `isin`? any other solution is welcomed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of **piRSquared** with his `map` function, I had the idea to use merge such as:

```
df_s['value'] = df_s['sentence'].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'word':x.split(' ')}),df_w)['value']))
```

Thanks to the answer of  **Wen** with his `stack` function, I use his idea but with `merge` such as:

```
df_stack = pd.DataFrame({'word': df_s['sentence'].str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()})
df_s['value'] = df_stack.reset_index().merge(df_w).set_index(['level_0','level_1'])['value'].sum(level=0)
```

And both methods give me the right answer. 
Finally, to test which solution is faster, I define functions such as:

```
def sol_dict (df_s, df_w): # answer with a dict
    dict_w = pd.Series(df_w['value'].values,index=df_w['word']).to_dict()
    df_s['value'] = df_s['sentence'].apply(lambda x: sum([dict_w[word] for word in x.split(' ') if word in dict_w.keys()]))
    return df_s

def sol_wen(df_s, df_w): # answer of Wen
    s=df_s.sentence.str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()
    df_s['value']=s[s.isin(df_w.word)].replace(dict(zip(df_w.word,df_w.value))).sum(level=0)
    return df_s

def sol_pi (df_s, df_w): # answer of piRSquared
    dw = lambda x: dict(zip(df_w.word, df_w.value)).get(x, 0)
    df_s.assign(value=[sum(map(dw, s.split())) for s in df_s.sentence])
    # or df_s['value'] = [sum(map(dw, s.split())) for s in df_s.sentence]
    return df_s

def sol_merge(df_s, df_w): # answer with merge 
    df_s['value'] = df_s['sentence'].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'word':x.split(' ')}),df_w)['value']))
    return df_s

def sol_stack(df_s, df_w): # answer with stack and merge
    df_stack = pd.DataFrame({'word': df_s['sentence'].str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()})
    df_s['value'] = df_stack.reset_index().merge(df_w).set_index(['level_0','level_1'])['value'].sum(level=0)
    return df_s
```

My "large" test DFs where composed of around 3200 words in df_w and around 42700 words in df_s (once split all sentences). I run `timeit` with several size of df_w (from 320 to 3200 words) with the full size of df_s and then with several size of df_s (from 3500 to 42700 words) with the full size of df_w. After curve fitting my results, I got:
[image]

To conclude, whatever is the size of both DFs, the method using `stack` then `merge` is really efficient (around 100ms, sorry not really visible on graphs). I run it on a my full size DFs with around 54k words in `df_w` 2.4 millions words in `df_s` and I got the results in few seconds.
Thanks both for your ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `str.split` with `stack`  and filter(`isin`) the result , `replace` those key words to value , then assign it back

```
s=df_s.sentence.str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()
df_s['Value']=s[s.isin(df_w.word)].replace(dict(zip(df_w.word,df_w.value))).sum(level=0)
df_s
Out[984]: 
                      sentence  Value
0           hello life if good     12
1  i sell this at a high price     77
2           i sell or you sell     90
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function with a default value out of a dictionary's `get` method

```
dw = lambda x: dict(zip(df_w.word, df_w.value)).get(x, 0)
df_s.assign(value=[sum(map(dw, s.split())) for s in df_s.sentence])

                      sentence  value
0           hello life if good     12
1  i sell this at a high price     77
2           i sell or you sell     90
```